# Javascript и событийность, асинхронность, setTimeout

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, settimeout

***Javascript*** - событийно-ориентированный язык программирования.

```
function first() {
  console.log('first');
}

function second() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('second');
  }, 1000);
}

second()
first()
```

`First` - синхронная функция. `Second` - синхронная функция, в которой находится асинхронная функция, выполнение которой завершиться после одной секунды.

**Вывод:**

```
first

second
```

*Почему, если `first` и `second` синхронные функции, первой завершает свою работу `first`?*

*Является ли это особенностью языка программирования и его архитектуры, строения и работы? (или той же самой функции `setTimeout`).

Comment: Первой завершит свою работу `second`, второй `first`. А вот функция `function() {
      console.log('second');
  }` выполнится не раньше чем через 1 секунду.

Comment: Функции то 3, а не две. Так что, если вы напишите `console.log('second')` в конец тела второй функции, а `console.log('third')` в тело третьей, вы это увидите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `setTimeout` создается асинхронная функция (через которую выводится `second` после 1 секунды), как ты сам и написал - она асинхронна, другими словами: она уходит на второй план ждать 1 секунду, когда на первом `first`(функция)

По шагам, код выглядит так:

```js
0 (()=>{ // "main"
    0.1 const first=()=>{
        5 console.log('first');
    };
    
    0.2 const second=()=>{
        2 setTimeout(()=>{
            7 console.log('second');
        }, 1000);
        3
    };
    
    1 second();
    4 first();
    6 // some
})();
```

Тебе нужно идти и читать про **event loop**, [вот хорошее видео](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ) на тему, правда на английском

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Разве вызов функции first не должен произойти после того, как завершилась работа метода second? Посмотрел видеоролик, который вы прислали, спасибо за полезную ссылку. От того же автора нашёл инструмент, которые позволяет просматривать call stack (task queue) - loupe. И в нём как раз функция first вызывается уже после того, как срабатывает метод second.

Comment: @true-hacker а ну да, я просто как в математике `1 в уме` видимо держал... хотел перед инициализацией добавить еще цыфорки и мэин нарисовать, но не стал усложнять